# Order of jQuery bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

If I have 2 jQuery bindings as;

```
$("input:checkbox").bind("touchstart",function(){

}
```

and

```
$(document).bind('touchstart',function(e) {

}
```

Here input checkbox is part of the same document.

So my question is;
What will be the order of execution of these 2 bind ?

Will there be any clash between the 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure jQuery event is bubbling. Going from deepest child to root element:

```
               / \
---------------| |-----------------
| element1     | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |element2  | |          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Event BUBBLING           |
-----------------------------------
Thanks to www.quirksmode.org for this image
```

Heres a nice article about event order: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Im your case the checkbox would fire its handler first.
http://jsfiddle.net/EgyUZ/

Comment: What would happen in my case ? I mean the checkbox is part of the document in my case..

Comment: Worth mentioning, in the checkbox handler, you can add `return false` to prevent the event from bubbling upwards to the document..